# Deny Direct Download of video files from cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I have folder of videos on cpanel wherein all video files are stored.
http://www.example.com/videos/wow.mp4

Now I don't wont people start direct downloads without visiting site.

Please help what should i do ion this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Enable hotlink protection, this is the solution for you:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Hotlink+Protection

> For cPanel & WHM version 56 (Home >> Security >> Hotlink Protection)

To enable hotlink protection, perform the following steps:

go to: Home >> Security >> Hotlink Protection

1) Click Enable.

2) To allow specific sites to hotlink to your site, add their URLs to the List the URLs to which you wish to allow access list.

3) To block direct access to files of specific types, add those file extensions to the Block direct access for the following extensions list.

4) For example, to block all .jpg images, add .jpg to the Block direct access for the following extensions list.

5) When you block these file types, others cannot hotlink those types of files from your website, regardless of any other settings.

6) To allow visitors access to specific content through the URL, select the Allow direct requests option.

For example, if you enable this option, a visitor could enter http://www.example.com/folder/example.mp4 as a URL to access the example.mp4 file.

To redirect requests for certain content, enter the URL to which you want to redirect your visitor in the Redirect the request to the following URL text box.

7) Click Submit.